# Can't run peridot test suite from a git hook

Tags: php, git, githooks

I have made the following pre-commit git hook:

```
#/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Running pre-commit hooks... "
vendor/bin/peridot -c OS/Specs/peridot.php OS/Specs/
echo "Done."
```

When I simply enter this command into terminal, it runs all my tests.  However, when the git hook is triggered, I get this:

```
Running pre-commit hooks...
PHP Parse error:  parse error in /path/to/repo/vendor/peridot-php/peridot/bin/peridot on line 9
Done.
```

The offending line contains a bracketed array []. When I change to the old array() syntax, the error goes away (and is replaced with another one farther down).  Furthermore, when I run `php -v` in both places, I get:

**Terminal**
PHP 5.4.24 (cli) (built: Jan 30 2014 10:18:21)

**pre-commit**
PHP 5.3.28 (cli) (built: Jan 23 2014 18:02:48)

Why is my Git hook using the wrong version of PHP?  How can I fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: There is this at the top of the file throwing the error:
`#!/usr/bin/env php`

Comment: Hm... good point.  Now I need to figure out where PHP 5.4 is stored.

Comment: Try `locate bin/php` to see where they all are. Or, if your default is 5.4, just `which php` will show you.

Comment: Any chance this php location is likely to be consistent across platforms (mac/linux) so I can keep this in a git repo?

Comment: Not really, no. Macs have PHP installed by default, but many devs install a fresh copy from Homebrew or Macports (mainly to avoid upsetting the OS installation), and these have their own default locations. And different Linux distros aren't guaranteed either.  You might want to use a shell script to either (a) look up the PHP path in a config file, or (b) if you want to get really clever, use `locate` and then auto-detect the version from `php -v`. I'd just go with the first one, defaulting to `php` if no config file is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `vendor/bin/peridot` is a PHP script, since you pointed out it starts with a PHP hashbang (`#!/usr/bin/env php`). It looks like your Git environment has a different `PATH` to your usual user account, and so it sees an older version of PHP first.

The trick in this case is to hardwire the version of PHP in your commit hook, so it doesn't have to do any `PATH` searching.